# ¿Cómo hago que las cajas "div" tengan la misma altura?

Tags: html, css

estos `div` son responsive pero no se como hacer que las cajas tengan la misma altura, ahora es variable segun la cantidad de lineas de texto, pero me gustaría que por línea quedasen a la misma altura
adjunto mi codigo y una imagen de como queda actualmente[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
gracias anticipadas!!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">window["_gaUserPrefs"] = { ioo : function() { return true; } }</script>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <style>
                body, html {
                  height: 100%;
                  margin: 0;
                  font: 400 15px/1.8 "Lato", sans-serif;
                  color: #777;
                  background-color: #2c2b2b;
                }
            
            
 /* header */    
            
                .slogan {
                  letter-spacing: 4px;
                }
            
            * {box-sizing: border-box;}
            .header {                   
              overflow: hidden;
              background-color: black;
              padding: 20px 10px;
            }

            .header a {
              float: left;
              color: white;
              text-align: center;
              padding: 12px;
              text-decoration: none;
              font-size: 15px; 
              line-height: 25px;
              border-radius: 4px;
            }

            .header a.logo {
              font-size: 25px;
              font-weight: bold;
            }

            .header a:hover {
              background-color: #ddd;
              color: black;
            }

            .header a.active {
              background-color: gray;
              color: white;
            }

            .header-right {
              float: right;
            }                                  
/* fin header */
            
/* un trozo de parallax */
                .bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3, .bgimg-4, .bgimg-5, .bgimg-6 {
                  position: relative;
                  opacity: 0.90;
                  background-attachment: fixed;
                  background-position: center;
                  background-repeat: no-repeat;
                  background-size: cover;
                }

                .bgimg-3 {
                  background-image: url("images/0023fantasia.jpg");
                  min-height: 400px;
                }
                .caption {
                  position: absolute;
                  left: 0;
                  top: 50%;
                  width: 100%;
                  text-align: center;
                  color: #000;
                }

                .caption span.border {
                  background-color: #111;
                  color: #fff;
                  padding: 18px;
                  font-size: 25px;
                  letter-spacing: 10px;
                }

            h3{
                color: white;
                font: 400 15px/1.4 "Lato", sans-serif;    /* el 1.4 es el interlineado, 15px es el tamaño de la tipografia */  
            }
            
 
/* tienda */             
              
            .tienda{
                width: 100%;
                float: left;
                overflow: auto;
            }
            .prod-2{
                float: left;
            }
            
            .articulo{
                width: 50%;
                float: left;
                overflow: auto;
                min-width: 400px;
                background-color: #121D2B;
            }
            .articulo img {
                width: 45%;
                overflow: hidden;
                float: left;
            }

            h2{
                font: 400 20px/1.2 "Lato", sans-serif;
                color: white;
                text-transform: uppercase;    /* convierte minusculas a mayusculas */ 
            }
            .textos{
                width: 50%;
                padding-left: 3%;
                float: left;
                overflow: auto;
                line-height: normal;
            }
            .descripcion{
                color: white;
                font: 400 15px/1.2 "Lato", sans-serif;
            }
            .precio{
                text-align: right;
                font-weight: 600;
                color: grey;
            }
            
  /* fin tienda */              
            
            .espacio{
                height: 25%;
            }
            .mapa{
                padding: 20x;
            }
            
            
/* tablets y moviles */
        /* parallax */          
                /* Turn off parallax scrolling for tablets and phones */
                @media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
                    .bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3, .bgimg-4, .bgimg-5, .bgimg-6 {
                        background-attachment: scroll;
                    }
                 
     /* cabecera/header */
                 @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
                      .header a {
                        float: none;
                        display: block;
                        text-align: left;
                      }
                      .header-right {
                        float: none;
                      }   
                }
        </style>
</head>





<body>

<div class="header">
<a href="index.html" class="slogan">Abert Díaz fotógrafo</a>  
  <div class="header-right">
    <a href="index.html">Inicio</a>
    <a href="gallery.html">galería</a>
    <a href="antes.html">antes y después</a>
    <a class="active" href="tienda.html">tienda</a>
    <a href="sesiones.html">sesiones</a>
    <a href="#contacto">contacto</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bgimg-3">
  <div class="caption">
    <span class="border" style="background-color:transparent;font-size:25px;color: #f7f7f7;">TIENDA</span>
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>


<!-- tienda --> 

<div class="tienda">
   
   <div class="prod-2">
    <div class="productos">
       <div class="articulo">
           <div class="imagen">
                <img src="images/CANVAS-3cms.jpg" alt="canvas">
            </div>
            <div class="textos">
                <h2>Sesión de fotos<br> en exteriores</h2>
                <p class="descripcion">toma de fotos en exteriores, sesión de 1-3 horas, con hasta 3 cambios de vestuario
                <br>hasta 50 kms desde Granollers, otros consultar
                <br>se entrega:
                <br><strong>book con 20 fotografías retocadas (retoque no fantasía)</strong><br>más 20 imágenes digitales  de alta calidad (para poder imprimirse) 
                <br>más 20 archivos adaptados a redes sociales</p>
                <p class="precio">80€<br>otras opciones consultar</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
       
     <div class="productos">
       <div class="articulo">
           <div class="imagen">
                <img src="images/CANVAS-3cms.jpg" alt="canvas">
            </div>
            <div class="textos">
                <h2>Sesión de fotos<br> en estudio</h2>
                <p class="descripcion">toma de fotos en estudio fotográfico<br>entrega de todas las fotos en alta calidad<br>entrega de 20 fotos retocadas (retoque no fantasía)</p>
                <p class="precio">99€<br>otras opciones consultar</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div> 

        
 <div class="prod-2">                       
     <div class="productos">
       <div class="articulo">
           <div class="imagen">
                <img src="images/CANVAS-3cms.jpg" alt="canvas">
            </div>
            <div class="textos">
                <h2>Retoque de imágenes<br> modo fantasía</h2>
                <p class="descripcion">para cada una de las fotos tomada en estudio o exteriores que se desee</p>
                <p class="precio">25€<br>a partir de 5 fotos consultar precio</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
        
     <div class="productos">
       <div class="articulo">
           <div class="imagen">
                <img src="images/CANVAS-3cms.jpg" alt="canvas">
            </div>
            <div class="textos">
                <h2>Sesión de fotos en exteriores</h2>
                <p class="descripcion">toma de fotos en exteriores<br>hasta 50 kms desde Granollers, otros consultar<br>entrega de todas las fotos en alta calidad<br>entrega de 5 fotos retocadas (retoque no fantasía)</p>
                <p class="precio">99€<br>otras opciones consultar</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
  </div>     
        
  <div class="prod-2">     
     <div class="productos">
       <div class="articulo">
           <div class="imagen">
                <img src="images/CANVAS-3cms.jpg" alt="canvas">
            </div>
            <div class="textos">
                <h2>Sesión de fotos en exteriores</h2>
                <p class="descripcion">toma de fotos en exteriores<br>hasta 50 kms desde Granollers, otros consultar<br>entrega de todas las fotos en alta calidad<br>entrega de 5 fotos retocadas (retoque no fantasía)</p>
                <p class="precio">99€<br>otras opciones consultar</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
       
     <div class="productos">
       <div class="articulo">
           <div class="imagen">
                <img src="images/CANVAS-3cms.jpg" alt="canvas">
            </div>
            <div class="textos">
                <h2>Sesión de fotos en exteriores</h2>
                <p class="descripcion">toma de fotos en exteriores<br>hasta 50 kms desde Granollers, otros consultar<br>entrega de todas las fotos en alta calidad<br>entrega de 5 fotos retocadas (retoque no fantasía)</p>
                <p class="precio">99€<br>otras opciones consultar</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
 </div>        
</div>
        


<!-- contacto -->    



<footer>  
    <section id="contacto"></section>      <!-- es para anclajes -->
    <br>
    <p class="contacto" style="color:#ddd; text-align: center;"><b>Contacto: </b> <br> hola@albertfotografo.com  <br>    tel 622 103 913 <br> C. Sant Jaume 52, 08402 Granollers (Cita previa)   </p>   
    <br><br>
    <div class="social" style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/AlbertDiazFashionPhotographer" target="_blank"> <img src="images/Social-Media-facebook.png" alt="instagram"></a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wl3_hAFs1gM&t=7s" target="_blank"> <img src="images/Social-Media-youtube.png" alt="youtube"></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/albertdiazart/" target="_blank"> <img src="images/Social-Media-instagram.png" alt="instagram"></a>
        <br><br>
    </div>
    
</footer> 


</body></html>
```

Comment: Hay una forma de lograrlo muy sencilla, solo usa flexbox y no necesitaras una altura definida para cada elemento. Te dejo una respuesta más amplia, cualquier duda, me escribes.

Answer (score 2):

Para lograrlo es muy sencillo, solo falta que al contenedor de cada cuadro u opción, tenga un **`display: Flex;`** y para que no ocupen todos los hijos la misma linea, usa la propiedad **`flex-wrap: wrap;`** Así:

```
.contenedor{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Siguiendo el mismo ejemplo de la imagen, hice esta demo, que creo se ajusta a tu caso:

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  background-color: #d6d6d9;
  padding: 2em;
  font-size: 14px;  
}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.option{
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: MidnightBlue;
}

.option .container{
  padding: .5em 1.5em 1.5em;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.option h3{
  padding: 1em 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: light;
  font-family: arial;
}

.option p{
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.media_img{
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.option .precio{
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.6;   
  text-align: right;
  padding: 1em;
}

.option:nth-child(4n+2),
.option:nth-child(4n+3){
  box-shadow: inset 100em 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1); 
}

@media (min-width: 840px){
  .option .container{
    width: 60%;
  }
}
/*
@media (min-width: 720px){
  .option{
    width: 50%;
  }
  
  .option:nth-child(4n+2),
  .option:nth-child(4n+3){
    box-shadow: inset 100em 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1); 
  }
}

@media (min-width: 960px){
  .option{
    width: calc(100% / 3);
  }
  
  .option:nth-child(4n+3){
    box-shadow: none; 
  }
  
  .option:nth-child(even){
    box-shadow: inset 100em 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1); 
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px){
  .option{
    width: 25%;
  }  
  
  .option:nth-child(even){
    box-shadow: none; 
  }
  
  .option:nth-child(5n+2),
  .option:nth-child(5n+4),
  .option:nth-child(5n+5){
    box-shadow: inset 100em 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1); 
  }
}*/
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<section class="wrapper">
  <div class="option">
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/600/400" alt="" class="media_img">
    <div class="container">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure sed quis eaque aliquid optio quo voluptatibus quas ut consequatur praesentium alias deleniti odio, quaerat, totam sunt veniam? </p>
      <p class="precio">7$</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="option">
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/600/400" alt="" class="media_img">
    <div class="container">
      <h3> consectetur adipisicing elit</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta temporibus quo ea repellendus pariatur ad. Excepturi</p>
      <p class="precio">
        2$
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="option">
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/600/400" alt="" class="media_img">
    <div class="container">
      <h3>LAliquid voluptatibus impedit ex?</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur odio impedit quisquam animi id exercitationem, cumque, vel iste expedita neque labore. Quia possimus est repellat unde facere consequuntur? Pariatur, voluptate.</p>
      <p class="precio">4$</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="option">
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/600/400" alt="" class="media_img">
    <div class="container">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat corporis accusamus</h3>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores dolore consequatur assumenda doloribus ullam quo error sapiente est dolor impedit. Tempore deleniti dicta soluta voluptate veritatis quibusdam nobis corporis vero!</p>
      <p class="precio">8$</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="option">
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/600/400" alt="" class="media_img">
    <div class="container">
      <h3>Iste corrupti ducimus dignissimos eius</h3>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt dolore fugit, aut, molestiae tempora natus repellat distinctio, quisquam repellendus necessitatibus odit nemo quia magnam. Debitis ratione sunt odio accusamus. Aliquam. Ut, impedit fugiat quam provident distinctio aut eaque ex possimus illum quisquam sapiente iusto assumenda dolor ipsam est quia. Cupiditate, facilis minus?</p>
      <p class="precio">3$</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="option">
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/600/400" alt="" class="media_img">
    <div class="container">
      <h3>deleniti odit qui architecto saepe distinctio!</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea, odio temporibus. Laudantium quis consequuntur numquam, quaerat hic asperiores! Impedit eligendi consequuntur officia facere, reprehenderit nam pariatur quia nihil sequi laudantium.</p>
      <p class="precio">1$</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="option">
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/600/400" alt="" class="media_img">
    <div class="container">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea, odio temporibus. Laudantium quis consequuntur numquam, quaerat hic asperiores! Impedit eligendi consequuntur officia facere, reprehenderit.</p>
      <p class="precio">6$</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

En caso de no ser así, déjame tu comentario. Éxitos!

---

### Actualización

> pero le falta el tema responsive, tu que sabes tanto, a ver si lo puedes adpatar

De poder puedo, pero no entiendo el porque la pregunta, ya que simplemente basta con adaptar los estilos a cada braking point con el media queries que consideres, por ejemplo:

```
.option{
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 720px){
  .option{
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 960px){
  .option{
    width: calc(100% / 3);
  }

@media (min-width: 1200px){
  .option{
    width: 25%;
  } 
}
```

No requiere de una técnica rara o algo así para que sea responsive, por cierto ya actualice la demo, para que veas como funciona.

Comment: muchas gracias Edgar!!! está estupendo!!! pero le falta el tema responsive, tu que sabes tanto, a ver si lo puedes adpatar

Comment: @Basicmix Actualice la demo para que sea responsive, pero lo hice simplemente con media queries, no hace falta más o alguna técnica rara. Por cierto, te agradecería mucho si aceptas mi respuesta como la correcta. ëxitos!

Comment: hola Edgar, ahora funciona mal, hay 4 cajas por columna y no 2 por fila y ademas son verticales y no horizontales

Comment: Me preguntaste como hace que sean responsive, entonces, en móviles pequeños aparece de 1 caja por fila, en tablets o smartphones de resolución grande 2, en laptops o minipcs 3 por fila y en portátiles grandes o monitores grandes: 4. Si no era así, ¿Entonces como era? Por qué no lo especificaste? Si es un diseño específico lo mejor es que lo preguntes en otra pregunta aparte para poder ver más detalles. Por cierto ¿Tienes experiencia con código css? es que con lo que me dices, no estoy seguro si entiendes bien algunas cosas que dejó de lado por ser muy básicas.

Comment: Si que lo especifiqué y añadí una imagen (la puedes ver arriba) queria 2 articulos por fila (vista para pc), con las cajas a la misma altura y responsive

Comment: Por eso, si son dos cajas por filas, antes estaba con width al 50%, eso hace que sean dos columnas, pero dijiste que lo necesitabas en RWD y hay varias tecnicas una de las que hice fue esa, pero antes estaba entonces a 2 columnas, como querías entonces que se viera responsive? A eso me refiero que no lo especificaste. Pdta: Vuelvo a modificar el código para que quede siempre a dos columnas.

Comment: He cambiado 2 valores al 50% del ancho para vistas de 960 y1200px y solucionado! , ahora solo me falta que en vistas de movil el texto pase debajo de la imagen, estoy en ello pero no lo logro...

Comment: Ah okey, entonces solo debes dejar la imagen con un width al 100% y lo mismo con el div container y en el media querie de 960, lo vuelves a colocar como lo tiene ahora, la imagen a 40% y el container a 60 y listo.

Comment: creo no te entiendo donde porque donde pongo whidth al 100% sale la imagen enorme, lo dejaste puesto en el codigo?

Comment: Si, debe salir del mismo tamaño que la caja, es 100% por lo que es obvio que va a verse más grande jeje, descuida, si solo quieres que la imagen se mantenga al mismo tamaño, solo cambia el ancho del contenedor al 100% y a la imagen no le hagas nada, el codigo no lo he vuelto a tocar, estoy desde el celular.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que al 'div' en el que contienes los productos, le estás asignando una clase que no tienes definida que es 'productos'. Prueba a definir la clase y a ponerle una altura fija al div.

```
.productos {      
  height:200px; //La altura que quieras
}
```

Comment: hola Alex, antes que nada gracias por tu ayuda! pero no me soluciona el problema y además el color de fondo no llega hasta abajo

Answer (score 0):

Una opción es ponerla fija como te comentan a partir de otra clase. Otra opción podría ser ponerle la misma altura a todos y que dicha altura sea la más alta. Esto lo puedes hacer mediante jquery, podría ser un código similar a lo siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var alturas = [];
    $('div.productos').each(function(){
        alturas.push($(this).height());
    });

  var maximo = Math.max.apply(null, alturas)

  alert("El maximo heigth es: " + maximo);

  $('div.productos').each(function(){
    //Aplicamos a todos los divs la misma altura
    $(this).height(maximo);
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2n196gyp/8/

Un saludo,

Comment: hola Brank, no se usar lo que me mandas, lo unico que se me ocurre es ponerlo en el "head" dentro de una etiqueta "script" pero no hace nada, es que se poquito :(, donde pongo ese codigo? he visto el enlace y veo que van de 1 por linea, en mi caso deberian ir 2 tarjetas de producto por linea. Gracias por contestar!

Comment: Ese código lo puedes poner dentro de una etiqueta <script> en el head o abajo del código html, lo que hace básicamente es que cuando carga la página obtiene todos los elementos HTML que tengan la clase productos y los recorre par guardar en la variable "alturas" el height de cada uno de ellos. Posteriormente obtiene el máximo de ese array y recorre de nuevo todos los elementos de clase "productos" y le pone a todos el mismo height. Para esto es necesario tener cargado jquery que lo puedes obtener en el siguiente enlace: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js

Comment: esto lo pongo asi, y sale lo que pido:
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var alturas = [];
        $('div.productos').each(function(){
            alturas.push($(this).height());
        });

      var maximo = Math.max.apply(null, alturas)

      alert("El maximo heigth es: " + maximo);

      $('div.productos').each(function(){
        //Aplicamos a todos los divs la misma altura
        $(this).height(maximo);
      });
    });
</script>